# Is there any way I can see my APM (Actions per Minute) in Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-apps

I am looking for a way to see my APM count while working on Ubuntu in my office. I used in Windows environment this program http://www.desktopapm.com/ but it seems that no easy solution available in Ubuntu.

Comment: see https://alternativeto.net/software/desktop-apm/?platform=linux  for what they claim as alternatives. Most are payware though and I have no experience with any of them

Answer (score 0):

I have one possible solution. I didn't find any app similar to desktopapm on Linux. However, I workaround this lack using Wine to install desktopapm on Linux (mint). If you don't have in your computer, I can download it bi this link:

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

If you aren't familiar with this tool, check out its home page. Then, you ought to download the .exe file in:

http://www.desktopapm.com/about.php

Run playOnLinux and try to install it using x64 architecture, I used the version 5.0-rc1-staging for the Wine. I think everything is going on well until now. Actually PlayOnWine is a very tricky app, It usually has some trouble. But as its app is very simple, maybe it works.

Have a look of this application running on my Linux:

[image]

I don't know if this program is tracking correctly the inputs that you are typing on Linux. Please give feedback if it is working fine there.

I hope to help you.